# Method to move arrays into rails ActiveRecord table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assume a model `Fruit` with attributes `name`, `price`, and `weight`, and assume three arrays:

```rb
name = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]
price = [1.5, 1, 2]
weight = [130, 110, 120]
```

Is there a method that creates a new record in Rails comprising the i'th element of each array above?

Comment: As always, the biggest question is - why do you need to do this. Such a setup is rather unusual and mgiht suggest some design issues.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity:

```
name.
  zip(price, weight).
  map(&%i[name price weight].method(:zip)).
  map(&:to_h).
  map(&Fruit.method(:create))
```

Comment: You can just pass an array of hashes to `Fruit.create` instead of calling it on each iteration.

Comment: @max I have no idea about how rails/ar do their magic, but ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a method but you iterate loop to add numbers objects inside `Fruit` as below,

```
name.length.times { |i| Fruit.create(name: name[i], price: price[i], weight: weight[i]) }
```

Comment: Instead of 3 you can also use `name.lenght.times`

Comment: @ts Yea, little more dynamic!

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of hashes by:

```
name.zip(price, weight).map { |a| Hash[[:name, :price, :weight].zip(a)] }
# [{:name=>"apple", :price=>1.5, :weight=>130}, {:name=>"orange", :price=>1, :weight=>110}, {:name=>"pear", :price=>2, :weight=>120}]
```

`.zip` merges arrays together. `Hash[]` is a special constructor method for hashes that takes an array of key/value pair arrays.

To create multiple records at once you can just pass an array of hashes to the create method:

```
Fruit.create(
  name.zip(price, weight).map { |a| Hash[[:name, :price, :weight].zip(a)] }
)
```

Comment: In Ruby 2.1+ you can use `[:name, :price, :weight].zip(a).to_h` instead.

Comment: Or even `%i[name price weight].zip(a).to_h` to cut down on the line noise even more.